# Expressão dentro de uma lambda dá erro

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Criei uma lambda e nela tentei criar ou uma expressão ou outro. Com ou(||) não funcionou. Aí, no lugar da || eu fui adicionando Where. É isso mesmo? Esta assim agora:

```
var resultado = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
                .Where(a => a.DT_TransacaoV < diaAnt)
                .Where(b => b.DT_ControleV < dataControle)
                .Where(c => c.DE_Cnpj == cnpj)
                .Select(i => new { i.DE_Cnpj }).ToList();
```

Comment: Explique melhor ta sem nexo o titulo sobre a questão

Comment: Ok, se eu fizesse assim: .Where((a => a.DT_TransacaoV < diaAnt)||b => b.DT_ControleV < dataControle). Nesse caso não seria essa a expressão, mas foi apenas para ilustrar. Essa expressão não dá certo, logo optei pelos Where. Isso serve para || ou para &&

Comment: Dá certo sim! o que é Dt_TransacaoV é um DateTime, e o diaAnt que tipo é?

Comment: DateTime também, é ium DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)

Comment: O encadeamento de `Where` equivale a um encadeamento de condições **E** e não **OU**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com `||` e `&&`

```cs
var resultado = 
  db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
      .Where(a => (a.DT_TransacaoV < diaAnt || a.DT_ControleV < dataControle) && a.DE_Cnpj == cnpj)
      .Select(i => new { i.DE_Cnpj })
      .ToList();
```

**Obs:** *Perceba aonde vão os parenteses*